# PIXI.js performance optimizations for large number of interactive circles

Tags: javascript, performance, pixi.js

I'm new to Pixi and was considering leveraging it to make a data visualization with a boatload of data points and labels. To experiment / get started, I created a quick app that renders a 100 random circles with labels on them, and included some basic interactivity on mouseover / mouseout. I've heard webgl will let me render thousands of nodes without issue, but if I try and set the count (on line 65 of the code) to 1000, my browser is almost ready to crash - forget interactivity. My guess is that I need to start looking at optimizations, but being new, I don't really know where to begin. Any advice?

Example: https://www.pixiplayground.com/#/edit/WngviYj6fbBpNjqdqET5P

Answer (score 2):

[PIXI.ParticleContainer](http://pixijs.download/dev/docs/PIXI.ParticleContainer.html):

> The ParticleContainer class is a really fast version of the Container
>   built solely for speed, so use when you need a lot of sprites or
>   particles.
>
> The tradeoff of the ParticleContainer is that most advanced
>   functionality will not work. ParticleContainer implements the basic
>   object transform (position, scale, rotation) and some advanced
>   functionality like tint (as of v4.5.6).
>
> Other more advanced functionality like masking, children, filters, etc
>   will not work on sprites in this batch.

This [example](https://pixijs.io/examples/#/demos-basic/particle-container.js) demonstrates 10,000 sprites. However, some major changes to your example would be needed:

- Put all circles/labels into a single ParticleContainer.
- If shapes/text are not supported inside a ParticleContainer, would have to pre-render circles/text onto a texture. (This would be faster than always drawing, anyways.)
- If nested containers not possible in a ParticleContainer the interactive resize logic would have to be done differently.

Comment: you can also cache the shape instead of pre-rendering, both are fine.

Comment: In addition to this already excellent answer, please consider that PIXI.Text is not built for speed. It has fancy font effects and can swap styles whenever you want, but at a cost of speed. Use BitmapText instead, which uses a ParticleContainer internally and is way faster.